# Securely store public/private keys in a database

Tags: php, security, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I want to store public and private keys in a database securely.

My question is therefore how do I store the private key in a database securely. (public key doesn't need to be that secure anyways).

I have two methods currently.

- Add a passphrase (i.e. the user's master password) to the private key and store that as a string in the database
- Encrypt the private key using a symmetric algorithm and store that as a string in the database

Are these methods sufficient?

Which is better or are they the same thing?

Are there any better ways?

**Update**
Some of you might be confused on why I want to even do this. My use case is a team based password management system. Public keys are used to encrypt a password (one for each user in a team) and private key with passphase is used to decrypt the password.

Comment: The first only differs from the second in the way the symmetric encryption works. They are essentially equivalent, but with the second one you can choose the symmetric encryption algorithm yourself. Both have advantages and disadvantages. Since you haven't presented requirements, this will be opinion-based.

Comment: My only requirement is that the private key is stored securely (i.e. if a hacker got hold of it, they cannot decrypt it). From what your saying is that they are essentially the same thing, but the 2nd method give me more control. Am I right? Is there any better ways? Also what kind of requirements do you wish to know?

Comment: Yes, but the second method also has a downside, because everybody, even cryptographers, are bad at implementing encryption correctly. While there is not much room for error, you can make it potentially insecure. As I said, this is opinion-based.

Comment: First off, you need to store private key only. Second - if this potential hacker got a hold of your database, you have a whole different set of problems at your hand - for example, you need to determine someone got into your database in the first place. So, the only possible solution to this problem is to have a database that's not hackable. Sounds great in theory, is hard to implement in practice but it's doable. Encrypting a private key or doing some silly transformation like that while using a relational database is simply one of those things that make us all go **WTF**.

Comment: @N.B I see why your confused why I want to store both public & private keys. The reason I want to store both public and private keys is because I am creating a team password management system. The way I have seen many other apps do this is through storing public and private keys. The password is encrypted several times using someone elses public key and they decode it using their private key, where their secret is their password

Comment: @ArtjomB. What do you mean everyone is bad at implementing encryption correctly. Surely you just use https://secure.php.net/openssl_encrypt where the key is the user's password. What else do I need to consider?

Comment: @YahyaUddin You posted a link to a fairly low-level function which allows you to choose your own cipher. This can go bad, depending on how you implement it. If you want a longer read, this is a classic explanation [If You’re Typing the Letters A-E-S Into Your Code You’re Doing It Wrong](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2009/july/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing-it-wrong/). Basically something high level is almost always a better choice. And a passphrase on the private key is fairly high level.

Comment: For PHP good higher level implementations AES include [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) and [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor). It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is likely better, because it's easier to mess up your own symmetric encryption implementation, than to use an existing one correctly. Passphrases on private keys usually mean just some form of symmetric encryption.

PS. I'm not sure why you're using private / public keys here. If it's for proof who uploaded the key - great. If it's for the encryption itself - why not just use symmetric encryption of the stored password instead? If all people privileged to read it know the password to the private key, then there's no big difference. The only thing you seem to gain is being able to cycle the keys without changing the passphrase everybody knows.

Comment: My guess on why private / public keys is so often used when not required/not appropriate is the developers do not understand symmetric vs asymmetric encryption and RSA is a buzz-word that is really know,

Comment: Private and public keys is extremely important in my use case and is used even by many team password managed system that I have researched

Comment: Symetric encryption is also not sufficent, becuase we want to share it with other users. see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134465/how-to-securely-store-passwords-for-an-online-team-based-password-manager/134492#134492

Comment: Yup, if you want multiple teams with different passwords, then I agree that pub/priv keys help.